# Incorrect sum when I join a second table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join, sum

This is the first time I ask for your help,

Actually I have to create a query, and did a similar example for it. I have two tables,

```
Report (ReportID, Date, headCount)
Production(ProdID, ReportID, Quantity)
```

My question is using this query, I get a wrong result,

```
SELECT    
    Report.date, 
    SUM(Report.HeadCount) AS SumHeadCount, 
    SUM(Production.Quantity) AS SumQuantity
FROM         
    Report 
INNER JOIN
    Production ON Report.ReportID = Production.ReportID
GROUP BY
    Date
ORDER BY
    Date
```

I guess some rows are being counted more than once, could you please give me a hand?

**EDIT**

if i run a query to get a sum of headcount grouped by day, I get:

```
  date        Headcount
7/2/2012    1843
7/3/2012    1802
7/4/2012    1858
7/5/2012    1904
```

also for Production Qty I get:

```
2012-07-02  8362
2012-07-03  8042
2012-07-04  8272
2012-07-05  9227
```

but when i combine the both queries i get i false one, i expect on 2 july 8362 qty against 1843, but i get:

```
 day      TotalHeadcount    totalQty
7/2/2012    6021    8362
7/3/2012    7193    8042
7/4/2012    6988    8272
7/5/2012    7197    9227
```

Comment: what is wrong with the result that you get?  Can you post some sample data and the expected result?

Comment: @bluefeet - It will be summing Report.HeadCount multiple times for each row brought in by the join.

Comment: @MartinSmith I agree with you, but I want the OP to clarify what the problem is with the result. The more details, the better. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group records per date using following

```
SELECT ReportSummary.ReportDate, SUM(ReportSummary.SumHeadCount) AS SumHeadCount, SUM(ProductionSummary.SumQuantity) AS SumQuantity
FROM
(
  SELECT Report.ReportDate, SUM(Report.HeadCount) AS SumHeadCount
  FROM Report 
  GROUP BY Report.ReportDate
) AS ReportSummary
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT Report.ReportDate, Sum(Production.Quantity) AS SumQuantity
  FROM Production
  INNER JOIN Report 
  ON Report.ReportID = Production.ReportID
  GROUP BY Report.ReportDate
) AS ProductionSummary
ON ReportSummary.ReportDate = ProductionSummary.ReportDate
GROUP BY ReportSummary.ReportDate
ORDER BY ReportSummary.ReportDate
```

Comment: Column 'ReportSummary.SumHeadCount' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 3):

This may be helpful

```
SELECT Report.ReportDate,
       Sum(Report.HeadCount) AS SumHeadCount,
       ProductionSummary.SumQuantity
FROM   Report
       INNER JOIN (SELECT ReportID,
                          Sum(Production.Quantity) AS SumQuantity
                   FROM   Production
                   GROUP  BY ReportID) AS ProductionSummary
         ON Report.ReportID = ProductionSummary.ReportID
GROUP  BY ReportDate
ORDER  BY ReportDate
```

Answer (score 3):

One way of avoiding this (subject to RDBMS support) would be

```
WITH R
     AS (SELECT *,
                Sum(HeadCount) OVER (PARTITION BY date) AS SumHeadCount
         FROM   Report)
SELECT R.date,
       SumHeadCount,
       Sum(P.Quantity) AS SumQuantity
FROM   R
       JOIN Production P
         ON R.ReportID = P.ReportID
GROUP  BY R.date, SumHeadCount
ORDER  BY R.date
```

Answer (score 1):

We have same problem but I solved it. Try this.

```
SELECT tbl_report.SumHeadCount, tbl_report.date, tbl_production.SumQuantity
FROM
 ( select date, 
    SUM(HeadCount) AS SumHeadCount FROM  Report GROUP by date)as tbl_report
JOIN
 ( select SUM(Quantity) AS SumQuantity, date FROM  Production GROUP by date)as tbl_production
WHERE tbl_report.date = tbl_production.date
```